# recyclerView Pagination in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-volley

I am doing pagination with recyclerView. that is working successfully.  But the problem is that when reload the data of next page then whole data is refreshed  means data of first page and others. I want that the data of previous page should not reload or refresh but also bind with next page's data. how I can do that. here is my fragment code:

```
final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URLs.viewAllLatestProduct,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    setLatestProductAdapter(response);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);




private void recyclerPagination() {
 rvLatestProduct.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int 
newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                linearLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) rvLatestProduct.getLayoutManager();

                    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager
                            .getItemCount();
                    firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                            page++;
                            loading = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount) {
                        getPagination();
                        loading = true;
                        Log.e("PageNO", String.valueOf(page));

                    }
            }
```

and here is my getPagination:

```
private void getPagination(){
   final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
    URLs.viewAllLatestProduct,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final String response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    JSONArray object = null;
                    try {
                        object = new JSONArray(response);
                        setLatestProductAdapter(object);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    }
                },5000);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){@Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams(){
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("page", String.valueOf(page));
        return params;
    }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean of reload next page ? how do you reload ?

Comment: means when I reload  the data of page 2 then this data will populate with first page and not refresh all data.

Comment: where is the code that perform the reload ?

Comment: see my updated question. i am sending request to server for next page from getPagination method

Comment: I think the problem is you notify the dataset change for all the adapter so it reloads all list items

Comment: where I am doing mistake

Comment: this line make the adapter reload the data `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`